# Separate date into 3 var (day, month, year) manually with string manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Separate date into 3 var (day, month, year) manually with string manipulation

for example :

```
DECLARE @str varchar(MAX), day varchar(max), month varchar(max), year varchar(max)

SET @str = '15/12/2018'
```

the result should be :

```
day = 15
month = 12
year = 2018
```

and for the last i want to concate those var into 1 var with date format in sql server

format date in sql server :

```
2018-12-15
```

Comment: There is Format function in SQL Server for this. Try this - select format(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')

Comment: Ideally, don't use string manipulation where more appropriate data types are available. If you keep your data in `datetime` (well, `date` or `datetime2` these days) columns/variables you'll **avoid** a lot of formatting issues. It's only when you start treating data as strings that formatting issues start arising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conversion function `CONVERT()` to convert the date from character string value and use `DATEPART()` function to get specific `Day`, `Month` and `Year` from the date.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(20) = '15/12/2018'
DECLARE @actualdate date

SELECT @actualdate = CONVERT(date, @string, 103)

SELECT @actualdate AS DATE

SELECT 
       DATEPART(day, CONVERT(date, @actualdate, 103)) Day, 
       DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(date, @actualdate, 103)) Month, 
       DATEPART(YEAR, CONVERT(date, @actualdate, 103)) Year
```